# Raspberry Pi on an airplane?

Tags: case

Can you take a raspberry pi without a case on a plane, or will TSA or other flag you for having something that looks scary?

Comment: This is way off topic for the site, as there is no good answer. It'll depend a lot on what the RPi is doing (does it have a bunch of loose wires?), how jumpy the TSA agent(s) are, and how much you "look" like a terrorist.

Comment: Considering this is more a question about the TSA, maybe it would be better migrated to the [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: Yes i recomend travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You probably can.

According to this [forum post on Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=13243), many have done this without an issue. Many, have sent boards with them through the air with little-to-no TSA people interrupting them. I would personally recommend you get a case for it, whether it be a paper fold-out, or a plastic one which I use [here](http://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-black-case.html).

**EDIT:** This is all an opinion, I can't validate that every time they won't get on to you, but from what others have stated online, whether it be true or not, you shouldn't have a big ordeal when flying with a Pi. As @Jacobm001 mentioned above in the comment, this isn't a good question for this site, and it can't have a solid answer.

Comment: So if many people have done it without an issue and you don't mention any reason why not, why the headline "probably not"?  Wouldn't "probably" be a better answer?

Comment: I was referring to the end of his question "will TSA or other flag you for having something that looks scary?". I did edit it for clarity though. @MarkSmith